# How to add an element in ruby Hash if given block type is integer?

Tags: ruby

```
def self.jq_column_models
  COLUMN_NAME.collect {|x|
    {:name => x.to_s, :width => 80, :format => 'integer' if x.is_a?(Fixnum)}
  }
end
```

I wrote the code `:format => 'integer' if x.is_a?` to add a `:format` when `|x|` is only integer type. But it isn't compiled. How do you express this code by ruby?

Comment: I cannot understand what you really want, however you are missing the argument for `is_a?` method.

Maybe you meant `x.is_a?(Fixnum)`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-tap)(yield self; self):

```
  COLUMN_NAME.collect {|x|
    {:name => x.to_s, :width => 80}.tap{|y| y[:format] ='integer' if x.is_a?(Integer)}
  }
```

Comment: a question: in a project of yours you'd write this or a two-line assignment + update with conditional?

Comment: This one, cause it railsway one))

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `:format` in another statement:

```
h = {:name => x.to_s, :width => 80}
h[:format] = 'integer' if x.kind_of? Integer
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def self.jq_column_models
  COLUMN_NAME.each_with_object([]) do |x,memo|
    h = {:name => x.to_s, :width => 80}
    h[:format] = 'integer if x.is_a?(Fixnum)
    memo << h
  end
end
```

Comment: any reason to convert a beautiful `map` into a verbose `each_with_object`? (which, well, does a map) :-)

Comment: each_with_object is verbose but beautiful method

Comment: Now I don't know if you are serious or just joking. You mean it's better to write `xs.each_with_object([]) { |x, memo| memo << 2*x }` than `xs.map { |x| 2*x }`? Because that's what you are doing in your code. `each_with_object/inject` are useful methods, but there's no need to use them when there is a more fitting abstraction.

Comment: Well, I thought that map doesn't fit very well, so I came up with each_with_object solution, but now I think Yuri Barbashov's solution is best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have to use two statements:

```
hash = {:name => x.to_s, :width => 80}
hash[:format] = 'integer' if x.is_a? Fixnum
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the other answers, a functional solution that does not involve statements. First, add this generic method to your extensions library:

```
class Hash
  def with_values
    select { |k, v| block_given? ? yield(v) : v }
  end
end
```

And now use it:

```
{:name => x.to_s, :width => 80, :format => ('integer' if x.is_a?(Fixnum))}.with_values
```

Of course this won't work if `nil` is a legit value (which usually it shouldn't).